# How do I use two document.InnerHtml in javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am trying to write a simple script to allow for a second box to open at the bottom of the screen when the form returns false. What I really wanted, is the form to jump to the top of the form when it returns false, but this code below is my second choice. But when I try to add a `document.getElementById("...").innerHTML = ...` for the second one, the form returns true every time and this doesn't work.

This code works with only one:

```
if (firstname == null || firstname == "") {
    document.getElementById("err_firstname").innerHTML = "<span class='errorbar'>*Required Field</span>";    
    return false;
}
```

And this code is what I am trying to accomplish but not working; I need to not allow just one html box to open, but both:

```
if (firstname == null || firstname == "") {
    document.getElementById("err_firstname").innerHTML = "<span class='errorbar'>*Required Field</span>";
    document.getElementById("err_allerrors").innerHTML = "<span class='errorbar'>*You Must Fill Out All Required Fields</span> ";    
    return false;
}
```

Comment: As a first step open the javascript console and see if any error is raised. Are you sure to have an element whose id is `err_allerrors` when this code is executed ?

Comment: Can you post your html code here?

Comment: With window.open? Assign a variable to the function and use variable.document

Comment: How does this question involve jQuery?